# WSO2 - Configuring JPA on WSAS

Tags: java, wso2

We are working on a WSO2 Application Server based project 4.2.1.
We need webservices communicating with a MySQL db. 
The technology we are trying to use is JPA, Hibernate.

We got webservices running, connecting to the db directly (using JDBC connections).
It is JPA configuration that is giving us problems.

We figured that JPA's persistence.xml should be in src/main/resources/META-INF/ dir.
The Carbon-Studio create==>CarbonApplicationProject creates only src/main/java

When we try to create src/main/resources/META-INF  and then try to create aar file, it does not include the resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Next we put persistence.xml in 
  OurPackage/artifacts/services/axis2/G3DataTest/resources/META-INF
Now the persistence.xml gets included in aar file. But we still get the error, when deploying the file on to WSAS.

We are getting an error:
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} -  org/hibernate/MappingNotFoundException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingNotFoundException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:124)

A display of Classpath before accessing persistence.xml shows:
....;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\hibernate-3.2.7.ga.jar;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\hibernate-core-4.1.2.Final.jar;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.2.Final.jar;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\Indu\wso2as-4.1.2\repository\components\lib\httpcore-4.0.jar;....

How do we place this persistence.xml in resources/META-INF/ dir ?
Is there any documentation related to this? Or any resource we can contact to get our issues resolved?

Java Code where error is happening:

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");

persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="myPU"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.indu.dao.Tracks</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://172.24.1.68:3307/SPORTECHRI"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
-Indu

Comment: did you figure a way to resolve the issue? If yes, can you provide details about configuration?